# workflow: how to create a related item when add an item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, lookup-column, workflow-activity

I have one list 'transaction', I have another list 'transaction log' with a lookup column link to ID of 'transaction'. When I add a new item in 'transaction', I want to trigger action to add a new item in 'transaction log', with lookup column set to ID of the new transaction item.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the ability to use Flows?

Comment: @Rekamanon Yes, i have. What steps should I use? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your exact Flow will look like, but it should probably start with the Sharepoint "When an Item is Created" trigger and include the Sharepoint "Create Item" action.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow on the "transaction" list to achieve it.

The actions for your reference:
[image]

In Start Options, set it like:
[image]